Int32 causing crashes when being usec
I have been working on this FNAF fan game for a couple of months now, and Im about to hit the 3rd stage of development. However, when making the last character and its AI, I ran into a bug.
An int32 Variable called "Stage" is causing problems and crashing the game every restart.
int32 Stage;
It is used in this BTTask:
void UBTTask_FoxyCountdown::TimerCompleted(UBehaviorTreeComponent& OwnerComp) const
{
    Foxy->IncreaseStage();
    if (Foxy->GetStage() >= 5)
    {
        FinishLatentTask(OwnerComp, EBTNodeResult::Succeeded);
    }

    FinishLatentTask(OwnerComp, EBTNodeResult::InProgress);
}

In PiratesCove:
if (Foxy && Mesh2) 
{ 
   if (Foxy->GetStage() >= 2) 


And in the class itself: `
void AFoxy::IncreaseStage()
{   
     Stage++;   
     UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("Increased Foxy's stage to: %d"), Stage);        

     if (Stage < 5)     
     {             
        TeleportTo(Positions[Stage], Rotations[Stage]); 
    
     } 

}  

void AFoxy::ResetStage()
{   
    Stage = 0;           
    SetActorLocation(FVector{0, 0, -100}); 
} 

int32 AFoxy::GetStage() const 
{   

   return Stage; 
}

Somewhere here, is crashing the game, and after some debugging(UE_LOGS that told me the number, and removing stage related code and it no longer crashing), it's Stage Being Used. This is strange because I have never seen an int32 get a usual pointer crash. One thing I noticed is that Stage somehow gets set to this specific number after a while: 1983924. And it is this number Every time without fail. Here is the level restart code:
UNightInstance* Instance = Cast<UNightInstance>(GetGameInstance());
    
if (Instance)
{
    Instance->IncreaseNight();
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("NightNumber increased to: %d"), Instance->NightNumber);

    if (Instance->NightNumber >= 6)
    {
        Instance->ResetNightNumber();
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("NightNumber reset to: %d"), Instance->NightNumber);
    }
        
    UGameplayStatics::OpenLevel(GetWorld(), DecidingLevel);

When it opens the level to decide if you want to go to the next map, apparently Foxy's Behavior Tree is still being used, and because its not in the world, its causing crashes??????? Why is it activating if ONLY THE PLAYER is in the world.
I've tried everything, and this is extremely demoralizing. Here is some answers to questions I have tried.
Please help, I've been stuck for so long
I tried:
1: I initialized the stage to 0 at begin play.
2: I check if everything is valid 3: I have a delay after the level so everything can load in.
3: Went to another level, waiting a while, and went to it.
No crashes after level restart.
Crash Log:
Unhandled Exception: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION reading address 0x0000000000000069 UnrealEditor_Fnaftsor_1905!AFoxy::IncreaseStage() [C:\Users\Askari\Documents\Unreal Projects\Fnaf-TOSR\Source\Fnaftsor\Animatronic\Foxy.cpp:26] UnrealEditor_Fnaftsor_1905!TBaseFunctorDelegateInstance<void \__cdecl(void),FNotThreadSafeNotCheckedDelegateUserPolicy,<lambda_7b55c7ba8662fcfaf661ffc30e516b98> >::Execute() [C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_5.3\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Delegates\DelegateInstancesImpl.h:862]

The Line In particular: Stage++
I also get the same error message from time to time, but instead of Stage++ its TeleportTo
I think it has to do with stage because when I remove code related to decreasing or increasing it(Or just getting it), the crashes stop.

Looks like you have undefined behaviour elsewhere in your code.  How do you use this code (please provide a [mcve])?  Does this point to a valid object?

The error message is clear that you have a bad address somewhere. How this is connected to the increment of a counter is difficult to discover without more debugging. It may well be that the pointer Foxy has somehow been destroyed.

The address 0x0000000000000069 is typical for accessing a member of a struct or class as offset from a null pointer. In this case, perhaps the Foxy pointer?

One thing that's happening is that IncreaseStage() Is being called when Foxy is not in the level. (However In the old build, it was doing it even if he was in the level, but it had to restart a couple of times*) Could this be it?                      *Side Note, in the old build, It always crashed after an Exact number of restarts (e.g 4, 2, 3) all correlating to how the level handled restarted(Like delays). The old system, didn't take you to another level, instead just restarted the current one.

Sorry, but your previous comment doesn't mean anything without being able to see your code.  Again, please provide a [mcve].

The question has most of the code associated with stage except for the Animation Blueprint(Which just gets the stage and plays animations). Is there anything you want in particular?
I put a check to see if this is valid and its passing, but still crashing.
Now Stage++ is no longer causing issues, but now, TeleportTo(Positions[Stage], Rotations[Stage]);  in Foxy.cpp and if (Foxy->GetStage() >= 5) in FoxyCountdown.cpp is causing it. You can see what these lines of code do above.

Re. "I put a check to see if 'this' is valid and its passing": given a random address value how would you determine if it's valid or not?  "Now Stage++ is no longer causing issues ... if (Foxy->GetStage() >= 5) in FoxyCountdown.cpp is causing it": as already stated you have undefined behaviour in your code.  Provide a [mcve] (please read that link).

Thanks so much for telling me about undefined behavior, I have never heard of this term, and after almost an hour of researching, I fixed the bug. You are a lifesaver.

Solution:
I fixed a lot of things in the FoxyCountdown BTTask,
1: Didn't try to set time if Foxy wasn't active. const float Time = Foxy ?  Foxy->MinimumTime + (Foxy->MaximumTime - Foxy->MinimumTime) * (1 - Foxy->GetAILevel() / 20.0f) : 0.0f;
Changed OwnerComp and this to TWeakObjectPTRS.
TWeakObjectPtr<UBehaviorTreeComponent> WeakOwnerComp = &OwnerComp;
    TWeakObjectPtr<UBTTask_FoxyCountdown> WeakThis = this;

Checked to see if The World was Valid.
if (const UWorld* World = GetWorld())
and checked if Foxy was in the world.
if (IsValid(Foxy))
